# Excel VBA Copy and Insert/Paste Special Values from workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone help with this Excel macro? I'm trying to copy from one sheet to another, but it crashes at

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong...

```
Sub Copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D26").Copy
Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\j\Trial.xltx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
rngDest.Insert xlShiftDown
  Err_Execute:
If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "Copying Successful :)" Else _
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Also is this the best way around pasting values and inserting the data?
Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Comment this line 'Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\j\Trial.xltx").Activate'. Change code to copy to Sheet2 - Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues See if that copy works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting parentage to all your objects and working directly with them, stayingaway from `.Activate` statements. Try this and make sure the `Trail.xltx` workbook actually has a worksheet called `Sheet1`.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim wbThis as Workbook
Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D26").Copy

Dim wbPaste as Workbook
Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\j\Trial.xltx")

wbPaste.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

rngDest.Insert xlShiftDown ' this is bizarre, because you never set this variable
  Err_Execute:
If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "Copying Successful :)" Else _
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code copying from Sheet1 and pasting to Sheet1? I think that is causing the crash the OP is experiencing as he is doing the same thing.

Comment: my code is copying from `Sheet1` of `ThisWorkbook` to `Sheet1` of `wbPaste`. It **explicitly** declares which *specific* Sheet1s to move between.

Comment: Thanks Scott, all works fine now but I need to find a way to Insert the copied data and shift anything below it down.

Comment: As you say, the ` rngDest.Insert xlShiftDown ` is bizarre (in fact it doesn't work like that) but I would be grateful if someone can help me how to do this.

Comment: @JG2703 - please post a separate question if you cannot get it to work, and we can help you *specifically* with that issue.